# How do I do Select queries on a table that is inside of a schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have an RDS instance set up on AWS. I can't connect to the PostgreSQL database without issues.

When I try to run select statements against the table I am getting odd results. It just lists the logged in user. The table is `User`. I see that the table is inside of the `public` schema. I tried searching for `SELECT * From public.User` but that fails. What am I missing here? The table does exist because I can see it with data in PSequel I just wanted to query the data using select.

Comment: "it just lists the logged in user" <--- does this mean that, if you log in to the database with user `johndoe`, the query lists `johndoe`? How do you know that there are several rows in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SELECT * FROM public."User";`. Postgres lower-cases the table names if you don't put quotes around them. I'd just make all my tables lower-case to avoid the trouble.

Comment: That was totally it. Thanks for the help. I love it when the solution is so simple.